# Using VBA to sort a named Excel Range using DIM to reference the named range and I get an error

Tags: excel, vba, sorting, named-ranges

I'm using VBA to sort a named Excel Range using DIM to reference the named range and I get an error

'Start by assigning the named range to a variable:

```
Dim Sales_Data_Range As String 
Sales_Data_Range = "Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo"
```

'This works (note that Sales_Data_Range works in ListObjects() :

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSA_tab_name).ListObjects(Sales_Data_Range).Sort. _
SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("Rpt_AM_04_Sales_ShipTo[[#All],[_RowNum]]"), SortOn:= _
xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

'But when I substitute  - "Rpt_AM_04_Sales_Ship - with - Sales_Data_Range - in the code below, I get an error message

```
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(WSA_tab_name).ListObjects(Sales_Data_Range).Sort. _
    SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range(Sales_Data_Range[[#All],[_RowNum]]), SortOn:= _
    xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
```

I've tried using parenthesis and quotes but can't get it to work.
I would appreciate any suggestions.

This code from Brian Stafford corrected the problem
Change from:   Key:=Range(Sales_Data_Range[[#All],[_RowNum]])

'Use this instead

```
Key:=Range(Sales_Data_Range & "[[#All],[_RowNum]]")
```

Comment: You are trying to go from a string to a string built using a variable.  So try this `Sales_Data_Range & "[[#All],[_RowNum]]"`

Comment: I followed your suggestion and changed the code to
Key:=Range(Sales_Data_Range & "[[#All],[_RowNum]]")
This worked perfectly.  Thanks to you and Siddharth for such quick support.

Comment: Try `Key:=Worksheets(WSA_tab_name).Range(Sales_Data_Range & "[[#All],[_RowNum]]")`